# How do I display links in a mu4E message at the end of the text

Tags: mu4e

I prefer reading plain text messages in Mu4E. However, I do not like its interface of mixing links with text on the same line. Is it possible to have Mu4E collect all links and list them at the end of the message, and only put numbers pointing to such links inside? for example, instead of "The great conference to take place http://onlineconferences.com/?c=1002&t=1400 had been rescheduled." It can be "The great conference (1) had been rescheduled" then before the message ends, we have: (1) http://www.conferences.com/c=1002&t=1400

Answer (score 0):

Use a Python package, html2text (for my distro on Slint 14.21, latest is version 2020.1.16. Its description in the Slackdesc file is:  "html2text (turn HTML into equivalent Markdown-structured text)".

Try checking it either in your distro's package repository or using Python3-pip and do `pip3 install html2text`.

And to to do what you are asking for, just pass `--reference-links` option to it. So in your `.emacs` file, you do something like this:

```
(setq mu4e-html2text-command "html2text --reference-links)
```

You can tweak a lot of other options if you like to tailor the end result. In my opinion, it is a tool that seems to convert html to markdown. Good luck!